# Setting up two-factor authentication with Github, no longer lets me enter a password

Tags: github, passwords, two-factor-authentication

After setting up **two-factor authentication** on GitHub, I am no longer able to enter my password as you can see on this screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you use two-factor authentication with GitHub, you cannot use a password to clone over HTTP.  Instead, you need to use a personal authentication token with the `repo` scope, which you can create in the Developer Settings page on GitHub.

Note that Git will still prompt you for a "password", but when it does, you should paste your PAT into the terminal.  Because of the way most terminal programs, including Git, work, you won't see the characters that are typed or pasted, but they have still been entered.  Once you've pasted the PAT, you can just hit Enter.